# Random protein in 3D

Tags: graphics, chemistry

I would like to ask for help how to encode the following:

I make a random sequence of aminoacids to make a protein, but how to make this visible like this: `ProteinData["A2M", "MoleculePlot"]`, that my is a random sequence, and its not in ProteinData... For Example `FGATTLTTAFGATTLTTAUTVIDAUTVIDA`.
Thank you!!!

Comment: This isn't something *Mathematica* can do out of the box.  You are talking about [protein structure prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_structure_prediction), and it is definitely a nontrivial task.  [This page](http://www.expasy.org/tools/) and [this page](http://www.proteinmodelportal.org/) might be of some use.

Comment: Highly nontrivial indeed; consider using software dedicated for this sort of thing instead.